# update mysql table without loading php page

Tags: php, mysql, facebook, apache

i don't know if this is possible but i need it. I am trying to update comments table with facebook comments based on permalinks but the php file is not being loaded. I mean the job would be done in the backend.

i am not talking about ajax. the page never be loaded or triggered from some file. it should update periodically.

Thanks.

Comment: Search for `ajax` in google.

Comment: And search SO, there are extremely many questions and answers about this topic and your question is way too unspecific.

Comment: "i am not talking about ajax" - Thats exactly what you are talking about. What's to stop you calling an AJAX function periodically?

Comment: i know how ajax works. not that. i need update without any browser request or i am thinking it should be that way.

Comment: when i make that job the file requested by the browser, ttfb is increasing ridiculously. So it shouldn't be updated with browser request. requested file should get only the updated results.

Comment: You can do this with some `magician`, if you don't want to use ajax.

Comment: @Sahal And that magician is called [websockets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket). But not every browser supports it so it's kinda early to throw away ajax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably what you need is to write a service page (the page that do the update) then call this page periodically (with a cronjob on unix or using a schedule on windows).

Instead of a page you can use PHP-cli and call it with a commandline script.